# Why won't Rmarkdown overwrite open html files or files it has previously failed to overwrite?

Tags: html, r, rstudio, r-markdown

RMarkdown appears to no longer overwrites open html files. I've tried this on a couple of different machines and with lots of different files. As recently as last summer I was able to write html documents, render a new version and simply refresh the page to see the update.

On top of that, once you've tried to overwrite an open html file, even after closing it, no further updates are allowed until you delete the file.

Any ideas what might be causing this or possible solutions?

```
 library(rmarkdown)

# set up to allow the use of a different directory
directory <- getwd()
write(' ## Testing what comes out ', file = paste(directory, "nonsense.rmd", sep=""))

render(paste(directory, "nonsense.rmd", sep=""), output_format="html_document", 
       output_file="openPageBeforeRe-runningRender.html", output_dir = directory)

# open url
browseURL(paste(directory, "openPageBeforeRe-runningRender.html", sep=""))

# re-run render with document open
render(paste(directory, "nonsense.rmd", sep=""), output_format="html_document", 
       output_file="openPageBeforeRe-runningRender.html", output_dir = directory)

# close document and re-run render
render(paste(directory, "nonsense.rmd", sep=""), output_format="html_document", 
       output_file="openPageBeforeRe-runningRender.html", output_dir = directory)

# even with the document now closed it appears to be permanently unable to write updates to the html file

# once you remove the file you're allowed to write it again
file.remove(paste(directory, "openPageBeforeRe-runningRender.html", sep=""))
render(paste(directory, "nonsense.rmd", sep=""), output_format="html_document", 
       output_file="openPageBeforeRe-runningRender.html", output_dir = directory)
```

Part of the error message

```
openFile: permission denied (Permission denied)
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1
```

Comment: I raised it as an issue on github with rmarkdown but they figured it was a local issue with the file writing permissions https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/699#issuecomment-220360925

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be to do with permissions. It's not entirely certain but it might have been that while I had read and write permissions, I did not have delete permission, which I do now and the issue has cleared up.